# slider de imagenes con angularjs, ng-repeat y peticiones asincronas

Tags: angularjs, imagen, ng-repeat

soy nueva en angular js,y me ha surgido un problema al intentar crear un slider de imagenes. Me sucede lo siguiente: Cuando tengo un array "definido e inicializado" por default, el efecto del slider trabaja bien, pero cuando quiero inicializarlo a partir de la respuesta de una petición a una api, deja de funcionar, aquí el código html:

```
<div class="col-sm-5" >
                        <div class="product-images" >
                            <ul class="dot"  ng-repeat="slide in slides2  track by slide.image">
                                <div class="image-imitation" >
                                    <CENTER>
                                    <img class="text-center" class="img-responsive" alt="" err-src="<?php echo $UrlrepositorioImagenes; ?>NO-DISPONIBLE.JPG" ng-src="{{slide.image}}" isImage  width="60%" />
                                    </CENTER>
                                </div>             
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Código js funcionando:

```js
  $scope.slides2 = [
    {image: $UrlrepositorioImagenes+Url.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")+'.JPG'},
    {image: $UrlrepositorioImagenes+Url.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")+'-PO-2.JPG'},
    {image: $UrlrepositorioImagenes+Url.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")+'-PO-3.JPG'},
    {image: $UrlrepositorioImagenes+Url.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")+'-PO-4.JPG'},
    {image: $UrlrepositorioImagenes+Url.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")+'-PO-5.JPG'},
    {image: $UrlrepositorioImagenes+Url.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")+'-PO-6.JPG'}
  ];
  
  $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'http://GetArticuloDet', // link UserLogin with HomeController
    data: Object.toparams(myobject),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  })
  .then(function (response){

    $scope.dataArray = response.data;
},function (error){
    console.log(error, 'no se puede consumir datos');
  
  });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código js no funcional :

```js
  $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'http://www.ecodeli.mx/ApiRest/APIPaginaWeb/v1/PaginaEcodeli/GetArticuloDet', // link UserLogin with HomeController
    data: Object.toparams(myobject),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  })
  .then(function (response){

    $scope.dataArray = response.data;
     $scope.slides2 = [
    {image: $UrlrepositorioImagenes+Url.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")+'.JPG'},
    {image: $UrlrepositorioImagenes+Url.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")+'-PO-2.JPG'},
    {image: $UrlrepositorioImagenes+Url.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")+'-PO-3.JPG'},
    {image: $UrlrepositorioImagenes+Url.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")+'-PO-4.JPG'},
    {image: $UrlrepositorioImagenes+Url.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")+'-PO-5.JPG'},
    {image: $UrlrepositorioImagenes+Url.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")+'-PO-6.JPG'}
  ];
   },function (error){
    console.log(error, 'no se puede consumir datos');
  
  });
```

[image: Se muestran verticalmente]

Espero puedan apoyarme con esta duda, ya que he buscado y probado soluciones pero ninguna me ha funcionado.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Duda, lo que te responde el API tiene la misma estructura que lo que tienes como mock data?... Y como tip, trata de refactorizar un poco tu còdigo, repetir tantas veces la expresiòn regular se ve muy mal, y tambièn trata de hacer màs gènerico el mètodo que itera las imagenes para que sin importar la cantidad de imagenes pueda trabajar.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. El api me devuelve un entero, que me indica la cantidad de imágenes disponibles para ese artículo. De hecho, mi objetivo es que en base a lo que me responde el api poder hacer dinámico el tamaño del array que voy a iterar, pero empecé con pruebas simples y noté ese problema.